# c++ unmanaged dll used by dllimport in C# produces entry point not found error

Tags: visual-studio-2013, dllimport

I know this question has been asked here many times before.  I've read all those questions that I can find along with information outside of stackoverflow.  So far I haven't found an answer i can figure out that will solve the specific problem that I'm having.

here is the code for the unmanaged c++ dll header file.

```
namespace MyWin32DLL
{
    class MyWin32ClassOne
    {

    public:
        static __declspec(dllexport) int Getvar();

    };
}
```

Here is the code for the c++ dll cpp file

```
#include "MyWin32ClassOne.h"

namespace MyWin32DLL
{

    int MyWin32ClassOne::Getvar()
    {
        return 123;
    }
}
```

This code i've put together from various sources so it may not be right at all.  I'm not very experienced with c++ or dll's.

Here is the code from my silly little c# winforms prog that I attempt to access the dll with. **(edited to correct type mismatch as pointed out by  tolanj in the comments)**

```
namespace TestDll
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {

        [DllImport("MyWin32CppDll.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
        public static extern int Getvar();

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string response = Getvar().ToString();

            MessageBox.Show(response, "title", MessageBoxButtons.OK);
        }
    }
}
```

Now, at this point i understand that i'm probalby getting the "no entry point" error because of how the c++ compiler mangles the names of methods and functions.

From what i've read there are two things I can do to solve the problem.

Thing 1
Add extern "c" before my declaration so the name doesn't get mangled by the compiler.

```
namespace MyWin32DLL
{
    class MyWin32ClassOne
    {

    public:
        extern "C" static __declspec(dllexport) int Getvar();

    };
}
```

When i try this I get an error from Visual Studio stating that "linkage specification isn't allowed".

Ok, so I try thing 2 which is to use dumpbin to find the mangled name of my function and use the mangled name as the entry point in the dllimport call.

So i run dumpbin /symbols on my dll and i get no function name, mangled or otherwise.

```
Dump of file mywin32cppdll.dll

File Type: DLL

  Summary

    1000 .data
    1000 .idata
    2000 .rdata
    1000 .reloc
    1000 .rsrc
    4000 .text
   10000 .textbss
```

Next i try dumpbin /exports

```
Dump of file mywin32cppdll.dll

File Type: DLL

Section contains the following exports for MyWin32CppDll.dll

00000000 characteristics
554CF7D4 time date stamp Fri May 08 13:52:20 2015
    0.00 version
       1 ordinal base
       1 number of functions
       1 number of names

ordinal hint RVA      name

      1    0 00011005 ?Getvar@MyWin32ClassOne@MyWin32DLL@@SAHXZ = @ILT+0(?Getvar@MyWin32ClassOne@MyWin32DLL@@SAHXZ)

Summary

    1000 .data
    1000 .idata
    2000 .rdata
    1000 .reloc
    1000 .rsrc
    4000 .text
   10000 .textbss
```

Looking at that I don't see a mangled or decorated name to use.  But as a larth i use "Getvar@MyWin32ClassOne@MyWin32DLL@@SAHXZ" as my entry point and still get the same error in my c# program.

Obviously I've missed something.  How do I access the dll function from my c# program?

Comment: Getvar outputs int in your c++ but you are importing it saying it outputs a string

Comment: ooopps!  Yes, i tried a lot of different codes trying to find one that worked.  I definitely have a type mismatch from making changes.  I've modified my c# source to use the int.  The original error still remains after changing the variable type.

Comment: Can you make your function *not* a part of class, but rather a procedure? When a function in C++ is a part of a class, strange things may happen if it accesses the classes fields or functions, and even using DLLs of one C++ class compiled with one compiler with another compiler is problematic, yet  alone impossible in most compliers

Comment: @Mark Segal.  In this case it doesn't need to be in a class.  I guess i was using a class because that was in one of the examples I saw. I will try it without a class and report back. It will be tomorrow before I'll get a chance to do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The name has been mangled, as you have observed. You've managed to omit the `?` at the beginning of the mangled name. Your import should be:

```
[DllImport("MyWin32CppDll.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl,
    EntryPoint = "?Getvar@MyWin32ClassOne@MyWin32DLL@@SAHXZ")]
public static extern int Getvar();
```

Do note also that your function uses the cdecl calling convention.

Comment: I made the changes you recommended and everything worked.  Thank you.  I can't believe that I missed the "?".  This answer solves the problem, but i'm also going to take the advice from Mark Segal and _not_ have everything in a class since it doesn't need to be.